# cool-retro-term --program not launching a program

Tags: terminal

I wanted to make an sxhkd keyboard shortcut to launch lf in `cool-retro-term`, but the `--program` option doesn't work. I tried just typing

```
cool-retro-term --program top
```

into the terminal, but even that doesn't launch top. It just starts `cool-retro-term`.

I even tried `cool-retro-term --program htop`, and that didn't launch `htop` either.

Because I've never played around with the options before, I tried using the `--fullscreen` option, which did work.

Now the application starts in fullscreen mode every time, even without using the `--fullscreen` option.

Could someone please explain what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `--program` parameter documented in the man page that I have for `cool-retro-term`.

Instead, the `-e` option is indicated:

```
-e COMMAND
   Command to execute. This should be used as the last option.  All
   the arguments following COMMAND will be passed to said command.
```

Use:

`cool-retro-term -e top`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try that. Very strange however, I'm not at home so I can't check, but I distinctly remember reading the man for it on my home PC said --program <prog> maybe it's an old version I'm running.